# Expected array-like (array or non-string sequence), got None

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, machine-learning

I have this code:

```
X, y = make_classification(n_features=2,n_redundant=0,n_samples=400, random_state=17)
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X,y,test_size=0.3,random_state=17)

clf = DecisionTree(max_depth=4, criterion='gini')
clf.fit(X_train, y_train)

y_pred = clf.predict(X_test)
prob_pred = clf.predict_proba(X_test)
accuracy = accuracy_score(y_test,y_pred)
```

However, there is an error `Expected array-like (array or non-string sequence), got None` in the last line `accuracy = accuracy_score(y_test,y_pred)`. How can I fix it?

Comment: `y_test` and/or `y_pred` are `None`, debug your program and see where you don't get the expected values.

Comment: @Guy, you are absolutely right, I have 'None' in 'y_pred'. How to solve?

Comment: Do you mean `DecisionTreeClassifier`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code with a minor fix works well:

```
from sklearn.datasets import make_classification
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score

X, y = make_classification(n_features=2,n_redundant=0,n_samples=400, random_state=17)
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X,y,test_size=0.3,random_state=17)

clf = DecisionTreeClassifier(max_depth=4, criterion='gini')  # Not DecisionTree
clf.fit(X_train, y_train)

y_pred = clf.predict(X_test)
prob_pred = clf.predict_proba(X_test)
accuracy = accuracy_score(y_test,y_pred)
```

Output:

```
>>> accuracy
0.8833333333333333
```